# Modern Browsers IE , Firefox and Chrome iframe support

Tags: html, iframe, cross-browser

As I was upgrading a site to use bootstrap css I noticed a page that has an iframe that it uses.  Another developer claims it works only in IE, but I cannot get it to work in IE, FF or Chrome.   FF and Chrome display nothing, while IE 11 blows up trying to load the pdf.

The code that is literally in the view source of what the browsers are trying to read just doesn't look quite right to me.  Thoughts?

```
<iframe id="ContentPlaceHolder1_pdfFrame" width="720" height="590" name="pdfFrame" src="File:\\chc\shared\IntakeTest\Storage\WF_Test_20130702161454_2.pdf"></iframe>
```

Comment: Don't use `file://` URLs.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that later on...  Thanks